# If $X = \bigcup_{k=1}^{n} U_i$, how can we decompose a continuous function $g$ into function vanishing outside of each of $U_i$ using Urysohn function

Tags: general-topology

Urysohn function was introduced as a continuous function $X \to [0, 1]$, s.t. for two fixed closed subsets $A,B$ it is constant on $A$ (resp. $B$) and is equal to $0$ (resp $1$). Then it was said that for $X=U\cup V$, for open $U, V$, we can decompose any continuous function $g$ on $X$ into sum of two function, s.t. the first one vanishes outside of $U$, and the second one vanishes outside of $V$, if we assume that Urysohn function exists. We let $A = X \setminus U$ and $B = X \setminus V$ be two closed sets. Then we simply let $$g = fg + (1-f)g.$$
Then it was said that we can *consider finitely many open subsets* instead of just two. However, I don't see how it is possible to define such a decomposition. I tried to consider pairs of closed subsets $X \setminus U_i$ and $X\setminus (\cup_{k\ne i} U_k)$ and define Urysohn functions $f_i$ on each pair. I think there isn't any reasonable way to combine these into a desirable decomposition. For example, we could sum $gf_i + g(1 - f_i)$, but summands $f_i$ don't vanish outside of some single open subset. I tried some other ways, but couldn't come up with anything.

I wonder if I misunderstood the passage, and something else was meant here. If it is possible, please help me find the desired decomposition. And there is another minor question: do I correctly interpret that $g$ is implicitly assumed to be a real-valued function as Urysohn function was defined to be real-valued?

Comment: Which source are you reading this from?

Comment: @0XLR Grundkurs Topologie by Laures, Gerd and Markus Szymik